# Get value of the first row of tbody in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get value of full tr of my first row of tbody on page load and put it to 3 variable Id, Fullname and Address.

```
<table id="Mytable">
<thead>
   <tr>
     <td>Id</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Fullname</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Address</td>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Hello World</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Some Where</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Testing</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Some Where</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

i try these

```
 $('#table_para').each(function(){               

 });
```

Any solution of these?

Comment: There can be only one element with `id="table_para"`, so `$.each` makes zero sense. And you don't even have an element with that `id` at all. What a bad question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use this selector:** `#Mytable tbody tr:eq(0) td`

```js
var array = $('#Mytable tbody tr:eq(0) td').toArray();

var address = array.pop();
var fullname = array.pop();
var id = array.pop();

console.log('ID: ' +  id.innerText);
console.log('Fullname: ' + fullname.innerText);
console.log('Address: ' + address.innerText);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
#Mytable {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Id</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fullname</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Hello World</td>
      <td>Some Where</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Testing</td>
      <td>Some Where</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

## Resource

- [`:eq() Selector`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

  > Select the element at index n within the matched set.

Comment: i see result ID: ${id.innerText} not the value

Comment: @TheRock the ID of the second TR is `2`.  Your question states *I want to get value of full tr of my second row on page*

Comment: sorry i just update my question i want to get value of first row in tbody

Comment: i get an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined

Comment: @TheRock can you share the exact HTML you're using?

Comment: Ok i am using angularjs to load data from db and then i want to show the first row of my table with pagination

Comment: can i ask one more question with my code of angularjs

Comment: i will ask new question with angular js

Answer (score 1):

I think your HTML table structure is off. Try this:

```
<table id="Mytable">
<thead>
   <tr>
     <td>Id</td>
     <td>Fullname</td>
     <td>Address</td>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>Hello World</td>
     <td>Some Where</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>Testing</td>
     <td>Some Where</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
   var myRow = $('#Mytable tbody tr')[0]; //get the first row of the tbody
   console.log(myRow);
</script>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jeremiahc/pen/yvxYPK)

Comment: i see undefined not value of tr

Comment: Is jQuery embedded on your page?

Comment: Did you change you HTML structure just like mine?

Answer (score 0):

As in css you can ask for the first child in your selector. With :

> :first-child

Same for

> :last-child

In jquery it exist a function :

```
$("tbody elem").first ()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wrap your jQuery code in a function to make sure the DOM loads before you query for elements that don't exist yet.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myRow = $('#Mytable tbody tr')[0];
        console.log(myRow);
    });
</script>
```